# window.open to get back to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a popup (using window.open) it has another page inside it. Is there a way to get back to thet page from which popup was called ?

Or is there a better solution to make the popup (for example who has a form inside that I have to fill) and after I update parameters would send to previous page (where popup was called)?

Comment: @indow? Nice one. Anyway no, once the URL is not your own domain you lose any control over the window/frame due to security reasons. (you do not want website to know what other websites you visit, right?)

Comment: yes i agree. So can you suggest a solution ? I need a popup where i fill data and then send to page where popup was called . Maybe modal popups ? How peoples do this kind of stuff ?

Comment: If the popup is redirected to a different domain then it is a dead end, sorry.

Comment: i am confused about the different domain issue. i dont see it anywhere. you could always use `window.opener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener

Comment: thx i found solution with window.opener...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but you can try this way:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload = function(){
        var action = window.opener.location.href;
        document.getElementById('userForm').setAttribute("action", action);
     };
</script>
```

and you should have a `type="submit"` input button.

#### Note:

Also same origin policy should be followed means both should have same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can not **go back** and **re-open** (except undo tab) to **closed popup window**, but inside popup window you are able to **traversal back** and **forward** by using following way,

Use **`javascript:history.back()`** function,

```
<a href="#null" onclick="javascript:history.back();">Previous Page</a>
```

---

Another way you go previous page **`javascript: history.go(-1)`** function add into `<form>`,

```
<form>
   <input type="button" value="Back to Previous Page" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)">
</form>
```

---

You can also archive this by using **`window.opener.location.href`** by this way,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementByTagName('form').setAttribute("action", window.opener.location.href);
    };
</script>
```